# why isnt javascript 'For' statement working in array?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation, input

i have a script that creates an array of words from a sencence and then capitalises each letter
i am getting sintax errors whenever i run the script.
Here is all of the JavaScript that is related to the input and output boxes.

```
function validateForm() {
    var addressInput = regForm.addressBox.value;
    var postCode = regForm.postCode.value;
    var townInput = regForm.townBox.value;
    var addressArray = addressInput.split(" ");
    var townArray = townInput.split(" ");

    for (let i = 0; i < addressArray.length; i++) {
        var addressArray[i] = addressArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + addressArray[i].substring(1);
    }
    var addressCap = addressArray.join(" ");
    
    for (let i = 0; i < townArray.length; i++) {
        var townArray[i] = townArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + townArray[i].substring(1);
    }
    var townCap = townArray.join(" ");
    
    if (addressCap > 1 ) {
        if (townCap > 1) {
            if (postCode == 4) {
                document.getElementById('addressOutput').innerHTML = "Your address is: " + addressCap + ", " + townInput + ", " + postCode;
            }
            if (postCode != 4) {
                document.getElementById('addressOutput').innerHTML = "Please fill out the post code box";
            }
        }
        if (townCap < 1) {
            document.getElementById('addressOutput').innerHTML = "Please fill out the town box";
        }
    }
    if (addressCap < 1) {
        document.getElementById('addressOutput').innerHTML = "Please check your address for errors";
    }
}
```

the error is for the `i` in `addressArray[i]` and the `townArray[i]`
i feel like it is stupidly simple but im stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var addressArray[i] =` isn't valid syntax.

Drop the `var`, as you're not declaring a variable:

```
addressArray[i] = addressArray[i][0].toUpperCase() + addressArray[i].substring(1);
```